# How to Overlay Administrative Zones

Tags: heremaps

Given HERE's article [here](https://here.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sys_kb_id=2a08d8ea1b02199015e297d4bd4bcb96), it seems they have administrative zone data (like counties and such). So I was wondering if anyone knows how to display some of that information as an overlay on a map--probably as semi-transparent polygons, or as an additional tile layer--or if you could point me in the right direction (as it seems difficult to find much information on the subject).

I know country lines and names are accessible/modifiable by default in HERE's style editor, but more than that I cannot find.